# Maximum number of TFs agents connected to a TFS instance

Tags: tfs, agents

On Team Foundation (TFS2017) which is the maximum number of build agents that you can have connected to your TFS instance?

Comment: Why you have this concern? Did you got any related error or warning during your configuration?

Comment: No, I still doesn't have any error or warning but I'm exploring the possibility of use TFS for do desktop deployments. So for example install the agent on 1000 desktop clients and every time the build is ready deploy on each of those agents. (I know that is an scenario where TFS is maybe not best option, but is for get an idea of the the limitations)

Comment: No official article mention it, you can open a new thread if you have the issue in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any official document statement the limitation of build agent numbers with TFS for now. Also didn't get any related prompt info such as: `build agents have reached the maximum.`

For multiple machines, you could configure as much as you require, there is no evidently limitation.

For a single machine, it depends on the **hardware**. If your agent server is virtual, then it is already slower as compared to the physical, you also need to allocate sufficient RAM for it.

> **Can I install multiple private agents on the same machine?**
>
> Yes. This approach can work well for agents that run jobs that don't
>   consume a lot of shared resources.
>
> You might find that in other cases you don't **gain much efficiency**
>   by running multiple agents on the same machine. For example, it might
>   not be worthwhile for agents that run builds that consume a lot of
>   disk and I/O resources.
>
> You might also run into problems if concurrent build processes are
>   using the same singleton tool deployment, such as NPM packages. For
>   example, one build might update a dependency while another build is in
>   the middle of using it, which could cause unreliable results and
>   errors.
>
> [***Source Link***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#qa)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how many cores agent server has. One Agent will take up one core.